# File.open(readme) in setup.py isn't found

Tags: python

The `setup.py` file in a Python package I've sent to pip:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    #......
    long_description=open('README.md').read(),
    #....
)
```

The file `README.md` exists. When put a breakpoint in `setup.py` and execute it locally, it reads the file well. However, when I install it from pip (`pip install my_lib`), it throws an exception during the installation that it's not found:

```
File "/private/var/folders/ty/0nvksfhn29z_cjb6md2t3x8c0000gn/T/pip_build_alex/my_app123/setup.py", line 14, in <module>
        long_description=open('README.md').read(),
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.md'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
```

**UPDATE:**

I just downloaded my library from pip, unzipped and discovered that the file README, LICENCE, MANIFEST aren't in it. And they're in gitignore either because they exist at github.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, pip install my_lib

Comment: @jonrsharpe, please look at my update.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I needed to create `MANIFEST.in` with the following content:

```
include README.md
include LICENSE.txt
```

Comment: See https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/using-manifest-in/  for documentation on `MANIFEST.in`.