# PyPI & pip - installed package receive error reading README.md

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I'm trying to install the package I uploaded to PyPI but for some reason I always receive an error regarding the README.md that was not found.

When running locally python setup.py develop it works great, but after uploading a distribution to PyPI, I receive the error I attached:

This is my setup.py file:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import os

name = "AWS-Manager"
version = '0.2a'
description = "An open source project for managing your AWS resources easily in your day to day coding"
long_description = "README.md"
author = 'Asaf Nevo, Aviv Paz',
author_email = 'asafnevo1@gmail.com, avivpaz43556@gmail.com'
license_type = "GNU"
keywords = 'aws ec2 amazon servers vpc awscli'


def read(file_name):
    """
    Read a text file in the Root directory
    :param str file_name: the name of the file
    :return: the content of the text file
    :rtype: str
    """
    return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), file_name)).read()


setup(
        author=author,
        author_email=author_email,
        name=name,
        version=version,
        license=license_type,
        description=description,
        long_description=read(long_description),
        packages=find_packages(exclude=['ez_setup', 'examples', 'tests']),
        install_requires=["boto3"],
        entry_points={
            'console_scripts': [
                'awsmanager = aws_manager.main:main',
            ],
        },
        keywords=keywords,
        zip_safe=False,
        include_package_data=True
)
```

This is error when `running sudo -H pip install AWS-Manager`

```
Collecting AWS-Manager
  Downloading AWS-Manager-0.2a0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-9nio8w/AWS-Manager/setup.py", line 31, in <module>
        long_description=read(long_description),
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-9nio8w/AWS-Manager/setup.py", line 21, in read
        return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), file_name)).read()
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/private/tmp/pip-build-9nio8w/AWS-Manager/README.md'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-9nio8w/AWS-Manager
```

Answer (score 4):

A solution to this is to Create a `MANIFEST.in` in the top-level directory with rows containing additional files you want to include in the distribution, e.g.,

```
include README.md
include LICENSE.txt`
```

as reported to work [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29150804/file-openreadme-in-setup-py-isnt-found).
This solved it also for my distribution.

I don't know exactly what is causing this but it *might* have something to do with PyPI being updated to only support files directly hosted by PyPI [described in this PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0470//).